# Tutorial on running Gmapping

Tags: navigation, roslaunch, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there anyone who can get a link a forum or tutorial that can explain how to install, launch and run gmapping!???
Really read everything and not helping at all. even the ROS tutorials is not interseting!!!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239654/tutorial-on-running-gmapping/) by [Space](https://answers.ros.org/users/27006/space/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-16**:
If you've "read everything" and it didn't help, then by definition you cannot be helped. Instead of asking for additional tutorials, please try to follow the existing tutorials and ask questions or clarification about the parts that you're having trouble with.

**Comment by [Space](https://answers.ros.org/users/27006/space/) on 2016-07-16**:
I don't see the point of you answering if you are not helping.
Ok just to be clear the quality of the tutorials is not amazing to think that it is done.
the turorials is supposed to gve details not sending to another page that is not useful.
the troubleshooting part on ROS wiwki should be bette

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-16**:
Please elaborate on which wiki pages you're having trouble with. Maybe you can start with where the installation instructions are unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you already read this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials) ?

---

Originally posted by [anonymous27503](https://answers.ros.org/users/27503/anonymous27503/) with karma: 36 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1